# Pass variable values from one method to another in python

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to verify the values entered by the user, The values that are entered by the user are being stored in one method and its values verification is done in the other method. But the problem I am facing is how to use variable values from one method to another. How can we do this in python?.I am getting error-"userDetailsValidation is not defined" Here is my code:

```
from userAccountDatabase import *
def userInputs():
  userDetails=[]
  firstName=str(input("Enter First Name").upper())

  while True:
    if(userDetailsValidation(firstName, "FirstName", accountDetails))==True:
      userDetails.append(firstName)
      break
    else:
      print('Enter valid First Name')
     firstName=str(input("Enter First Name").upper())

  LastName=str(input("Enter Last Name").upper())

  while True:
  if(userDetailsValidation(LastName, "LastName", accountDetails))==True:
    userDetails.append(LastName)
    break
  else:
    print('Enter valid last Name')
    firstName=str(input("Enter Last Name").upper())

  dateOfBirth=str(input("Enter date of birth"))

  while True:
  if(userDetailsValidation(dateOfBirth, "LastName", accountDetails))==True:
    userDetails.append(dateOfBirth)
    break
  else:
    print('Enter valid dateOfBirth ')
    firstName=str(input("Enter dateOfBirth").upper())
  # return firstName,LastName,dateOfBirth
userInputs()



def userDetailsValidation(value, fieldName, database):
  print("The account does not exist with the given details,Enter valid First name")
  for entry in database:
    if fieldName in entry and entry[fieldName] == value:
      print("correct value")
      return True     
    else:
      return False

def printRequiredUserInfo(FirstName,fieldname,AccountNumber,Accountbalance,Database):
  for entry in Database:     
    if fieldname in entry and entry[fieldname] == FirstName:
    print(entry)
printRequiredUserInfo(firstName,"FirstName","Account Number","Account Balance",accountDetails)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's impossible to tell what is part of a method and what isn't.

Comment: Excess whitespace can harm readability as much as no whitespace.

Comment: Ok let me edit my code

Comment: You need to move the function userDetailsValidation above where it is used so that it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your userDetailsValidation function is still not resolvable when you call it in `if(userDetailsValidation(dateOfBirth, "LastName", accountDetails))==True:`

You can move the implementation of userDetailsValidation() before userInputs() or just move the call to userInputs() after you define userDetailsValidation().

Regarding your question of using values of variables from one function in another, you have multiple options.

- Declare the variables as global. This way, you can access them in all functions inside your module.
- Implement the functions inside a class and create member variables for this class.
- Return variables which is of interest.